# Changing the contents of HTML page depending on options on navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making an administrator portal for a band-website. The design is as follows:

There is a side navigation bar(on the left of the page), with things to be done (such as verify reservation requests, answer fanmails, modify band info, upload photographs to the gallery etc.). Clicking on these options should populate a form in the empty space on the right. I don't want to create a separate page for every one of them.

I have checked hell lot of websides for side navs, but i see they all redirect to links to different pages. If anybody could suggest me what all i should explore.

Comment: Perhaps you could tell the band you aren’t actually a web designer?

Comment: I suppose you're looking for those options to call JavaScript functions?

Comment: Look into [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp)

Comment: @ASPiRE Thank you so much. That was really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking about is called 'Single Page Application'. You need to use JavaScript for this. Best way is using JavaScript MVC frameworks like [Angular](https://angular.io/), [Ember](http://emberjs.com/), [React](https://reactjs.net/) etc.

Comment: Thank you :) Figuring it out.